# In Probabilistic Graphical Models, are Cliques and Clusters the same?

Tags: graphs, terminology, probability-theory

I am learning Probabilistic Graphical Models with the help of the videos on Coursera. I am in week 4 and I see cliques being mentioned often. But the graphs being discussed are cluster graphs. So are the cliques and clusters the same?

Comment: What are cluster graphs?

Comment: And which are "the videos on Coursera"? Are you folloing Koller's course? Have you checked her book, or Googled?

Comment: Yes the Koller's course. But I am finding it a bit hard to do the assignments. Yet to get the book though. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *clique* is a rigorously defined, exact part of a graph $G=(V,E)$;

$\qquad\displaystyle C \subseteq V \text{ is clique} \iff \{ \{u,v\} \mid u,v \in C, u \neq v \} \subseteq E$.

A *cluster* is more general, but also more nebulous. Here's what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) has to say:

> Cluster analysis or clustering is the task of grouping a set of objects in such a way that objects in the same group (called a cluster) are more similar (in some sense or another) to each other than to those in other groups (clusters).

So, a cluster also is a set of nodes that is "dense" in some sense, depending on the metric used. However, while is it always clear whether adding a note increases the size of a clique, it's not always clear from looking only at one cluster whether adding a node to it is better; the quality of a clustering is defined on the *whole* graph.

As the Wikipedia article shows, there are many notions of clustering. Cliques can be seen as one of them.